# Populate the new list by looping over the original list using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, loops

I have dataframe **gapminder** and every column is organized as separate list using code as below:

```
country = df.country.to_list()
continent = df.continent.to_list()
year = df.year.to_list()
```

I have created an empty list **country_1990** and I want to populate it with data from year 1990 by looping over the original list **country**

How can I perform this task? Tried this:

```
    for i in range(len(df.country)): 
        if df.loc[df['year']== 1990 :
            country_1990.append(df.country[i])
print(country_1990)
```

to check at each iteration of the loop if the
associated record is from 1990 but not working
Thx

Comment: maybe `for i in range(len(country)):    country_1990.append(country[i])`

Comment: `df.loc[df['year']==1990,['country','continent]]` ? then separate the series into lists